How to reorder catgorical axis for dot plot with error bars
Here is the plot I have, the data & the code

ggplot(data = TI, aes(y = VM, x = GeoM)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(xmin = L95, xmax = U95), width = .75) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.2, 1.7, .1)) +
  scale_y_discrete()

VM  GeoM              L95            U95
CT1 1.044493    0.8411629   1.296973
CT2 1.1004184   0.843248    1.43602
CT3 1.0081634   0.8162887   1.24514
CT4 1.0621437   0.7885893   1.430591
CT5 0.9211109   0.6730119   1.260669
CT6 0.9704301   0.7795527   1.208045
CT7 0.8890728   0.6610186   1.195807
CT8 0.9366766   0.7370134   1.19043
US1 0.5968839   0.213126    1.671642
US2 0.5991981   0.21634         1.659603

The plot is fine but I would like the y-axis in the order displayed in the data above.
I have tried making VM a factor, an ordered factor, and
scale_y_discrete(
  limits=c("CT1","CT2","CT3","CT4","CT5","CT6","CT7","CT8", "US1","US2")
)

scale_y_discrete(
  breaks=c("CT1","CT2","CT3","CT4","CT5","CT6","CT7","CT8", "US1","US2")
)

scale_y_discrete(
  labels=c("CT1",..."US2")
)

putting the aes in the geom_point statement and a few other suggestions I found online.
I also tried this trick using dplyr's mutate function
(https://r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html)
TI %>%
  arrange(VM) %>%
  mutate(VM = factor(VM, levels = VM)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = VM, x = GeoM)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(xmin = L95, xmax = U95), width = .75) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), linetype = "dashed")

Nothing I have done so far returns an error but it also doesn't change the axis order.  Suggestions are appreciated.

Welcome to SO! Perhaps you want scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) to reverse the order of the categories?

In your case with making VM an ordered factor, your order is reflected in the sense that the Y categories ascend upward from the origin. It sounds like you actually want the reverse order, so you could specify in the opposite order or flip it like ggplot(data = TI |> mutate(VM = factor(VM) |> forcats::fct_inorder() |> forcats::fct_rev(), ....

Yes, I think the confusion is that the Y-axis has the first category at the bottom, not the top.

Suggestsions here prompted me to keep experimenting and this code works.  Here is the simplest soltion I have found. ggplot(data=TI, aes(y= rev(factor(VM)),x=GeoM)) +
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(mapping=aes(xmin= L95, xmax= U95), width= .25) +
scale_y_discrete(labels=rev(factor(TI$VM)))

You can answer your own question if you like. But it would be nice if you ensured both the question and answer conformed to a [MRE]

Well, be aware that using scale_y_discrete(labels=rev(factor(TI$VM))) will only change the labels and hence will in general assign the wrong label to categories.
